# How to install Android Pay in non eligible countries

Tags: google-play-store, google-pay

I've just discovered that Android Pay is available in Poland since November, and I happen to have a card from an eligible bank.
The only problem is, that I live in Germany, where unfortunately this app can't be installed from the Play Store. But I'm going to Poland this weekend, which means I'll have a legit polish IP address.
I'm guessing that's not enough. Do I need to factory reset my phone with a polish SIM-Card inside of it (I have a prepaid one)? Or do I need a Google account, which somehow is associated with Poland (I actually created mine 10 years ago when I used to live in Poland)? Or is that not the right approach, and I have to do something else?

P. S.: I have a Nexus 5X bought in Germany (It also says "DE" on the packaging)

Comment: Just download the APK, that should do it, even while you're in Germany: http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-pay/android-pay-1-10-139978031-release/android-pay-1-10-139978031-5-android-apk-download/

Comment: Keep in mind there's a reason it's blocked in Germany: it might plain not work where you live even once you set it up.

Comment: @owlswipe I know I could do it, but it's a payment app, I don't want to risk it not being a legit apk.

I think the reason it's blocked in Germany is, that they didn't partner with any German banks yet. But since I have a polish card, that is eligible I might be able to use it.

Comment: @szosk Good point, I would trust apkmirror (and not really any other site) but that's just me. Can you try changing your Play Store region to Poland?

Comment: @owlswipe That's basically what I was asking. How do I do it? I tried changing my IP, but that didn't work. I've also read, that it's tied to the billing address in Google wallet, but I noticed I have an old polish card with a polish address in it, even with a successful transaction. I've removed it now, because that card doesn't exist anymore.
The only thing I haven't tried yet is the Polish SIM-Card Trick. I'll try it this weekend.

Comment: Try [changing your Play Store country](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/QXdA_Q3V1o8).

Comment: @owlswipe Thanks. The only problem is, I have 18€ Google play balance. I'll have to use it up first. You can only change the country under 10€ Google Play balance.

Comment: Interesting problem, try switching stores under a different Google account that doesn't have credit? Or just buy Nova Launcher :)

Comment: @owlswipe Somehow that didn't work, even though I set the account up with a polish billing address. But I've managed to get the apk. I've borrowed a phone from a family member that lives in Poland, and extracted the apk of Android Pay downloaded via Google Play.

Comment: Smart thinking, weird that it didn't work. Let me know how it works!

Comment: @owlswipe Adding the card worked, even with my original, German account. The only Problem is verification. For some reason the only possible way to verify the card is to call the bank. But somehow the number that they ask you to call doesn't exist. I'll contact the bank tomorrow and ask why that happened (Maybe because it's weekend)